# How to implement manual pagination in Webmatrix?

Tags: c#, razor, pagination, webmatrix

I'm using Webmatrix and the Gallery template to experiment a little bit.

I have so many questions but I'll start with this one.
How can I achieve pagination in Webmatrix? I'm not using a grid though. I have also jQuery working and would love to get it to work with it too.

This is my code

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("PhotoGallery");

var id = UrlData[0].AsInt();
var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT UserId, DisplayName, Bio FROM UserProfiles WHERE UserId = @0", id);
if (user == null) {
    Response.SetStatus(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    return;
}

Page.Title = "User - " + user.DisplayName;

var photos = db.Query("SELECT Id, FileTitle FROM Photos WHERE UserId = @0 ORDER BY FileTitle", id).ToList();
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div class="box_content">

    <!-- Small Gallery Content: Start -->
    <ul class="gallery small">

        <!-- Small Gallery Image: Start -->
        @foreach (var photo in photos) {
        <li data-type="buildings" data-id="g001">
            <a href="~/Photo/View/@photo.Id" class="">
                <img alt="thumbnail of @Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(photo.FileTitle)" src="~/Photo/Thumbnail/@photo.Id" />
            <span class="image-overlay">@Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(photo.FileTitle)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        }
        <!-- Small Gallery Image: End -->
    </ul>
    <!-- Small Gallery Content: End -->

    <!-- Small Gallery Footer: Start -->
    <div class="padding">

        <!-- Pagination: Start -->
        <ul class="pagination right nomargin">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Pagination: End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Small Gallery Footer: End -->

</div>
```

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it folks. :)